# JAVA saving file to csv format .txt

Tags: java, user-interface, csv

hey guys so i got a assignment where i need to create a employee management system.

i created all the basics like login system, employee registration form which saves it to a txt file.

The Problem is  i need the information to be saved in a comma seprated  value.

as of right now this is how it looks when i save -

1326262
steve
jobs
67
091234567

i want to be like this -
1326262,steve,jobs,67,091234567

also how do make it that everytime new employ is added it starts on a new line. do i need to make a loop?

IF U GUYS WANT I CAN POST THE CODES.

THanks for your help

Comment: Yes, please post the codes :-)

Comment: *"IF U GUYS WANT I CAN POST THE CODES."* That would probably be helpful.  You could use `StringJoiner` to build a `String` from various other `String`s which is separated by a `,`, which is easy, or you could just use a dedicated CSV library

Comment: actually i was able to make into a cs format. right now :). but how do i make it that when i create a new employee it saves on a new line.

Comment: i will upload the codes in a sec

Comment: when i post the code it doesnt come up properly. what do i do?